# C++: Derived virtual function is returning strange results

Tags: c++

I created a derivable class with a virtual function in a .HPP file, and then gave it a default return value in the class's .CPP file. Next, I created a class which inherited the latter derivable class and overloaded it's virtual function, giving it a new return value. However, the return value is not always the same (either the default return value or the overloaded return value). Can someone help me fix my code or find the issue. Thanks.

Note: I am providing example code, which I believe will suffice in displaying the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;

class Fruit;
class Apple;

class Fruit
{
    public:
        int Type;

        Fruit();
        ~Fruit();

        Fruit(int = 0);

        virtual const int getVal() const;
};

class Apple : public Fruit
{
    public:
        Apple();
        ~Apple();

        const int getVal() const;
};


Fruit::Fruit() : Type(0) {}
Fruit::~Fruit() {}

Fruit::Fruit(int type) : Type(type) {}

//const int Fruit::getVal() const { return 0; } //Uncommenting this results in function //always returning ZERO; even in Apple::getVal().
const int Fruit::getVal() const { return Type; }

Apple::Apple() : Fruit(1) {}
Apple::~Apple() {}

const int Apple::getVal() const { return Type; }

ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, Fruit b)
{
    return a << b.getVal();
}

int main(int *argc, char **argv)
{
    cout << Apple() << "\n\n";

    #ifdef _WIN32
        system("pause");
    #endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't overload or override on return type. (But then in the code you provide, you appear to be attempting to do that. Your code doesn't match the explanation. Fortunately, your theory is off-base, as the answers explain. :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, Fruit b)
```

This code constructs a new object of type Fruit using the constructor defined as `Fruit(const Fruit&);`.

An `Apple` is a `Fruit`, so it can be used as the argument to the Fruit copy constructor, however, the `Fruit` copy constructor makes a regular `Fruit` regardless of the subclass of Fruit you supply, and you therefore will just get a regular `Fruit`. This is somewhat confusingly referred to as 'slicing'.

Instead, you probably want to define your operator to take a const reference, so the copy constructor is not used. Like so, `ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, const Fruit& b)`

I'd also recommend declaring the copy constructor and assignment operator in the private section of the fruit class (unimplemented) so that you can never accidentally make this mistake again

Comment: How is the term "slicing" confusing? You slice away the derived data.

Comment: I don't see a reason, semantically, to prevent copying of the objects. It would have shown up this bug, but that's not necessarily a good enough reason. +1 for the rest of your answer.

Comment: Thank you Slavik81 and everyone else for your solutions. This solution was well explained, and fixed the issue. I will be aware of the possibility of "Object Slicing" in the future.

Comment: +1 for describing what slicing is, which I neglected to do. It's certainly a strange term if you've never run across it before.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I think it's confusing because you are not actually changing the object that is being 'sliced', unlike when you physically slice an object. On another note, you're absolutely right that he should exercise his personal judgement as to whether the copy constructor is necessary or not.

Comment: @Slavik81: No, but you're slicing off _potential pieces_ of a copy of that object. I can see where you're coming from, mind you. Perhaps "selective extraction" is more accurate. :)

Answer (score 6):

You are hitting a problem known as [object slicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing).  Because your `Apple` is being passed by value into your `operator<<`, only the `Fruit` portion of the object is being copied.  Thus, when `getVal` is called, it is being called on the base class `Fruit` instead of on your `Apple`.

To fix this, ensure that you use references (or pointers) instead of values when dealing with base classes.  For example, the fix here is to simply take a `const Fruit&` instead of just a `Fruit`.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, const Fruit& b)
{
    return a << b.getVal();
}
```

As the Wikipedia entry says, this issue crops up in C++ because "assignment by value is not polymorphic".

Answer (score 0):

You're running afoul of the slicing problem. Your `operator<<` is taking a copy of the object, not a reference to it. Since you didn't define a copy constructor, the compiler did one for you, and it's doing the wrong thing.

Comment: Well, it's doing the right thing. It's just not the same thing that the OP _meant_ to ask it to do.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that jumps out pretty quickly is that you're not calling getVal() by pointer, and since your `operator<<` takes a Fruit rather than an Apple, it effectively slices off the derived part of the object. Try `Fruit&` as the parameter for the `operator<<` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, Fruit b)
{
    return a << b.getVal();
}`
to this:
`ostream& operator<<(ostream& a, const Fruit& b)
{
    return a << b.getVal();
}`
and it should work.

In your implementation you are constructing brand new instance of Fruit from Apple.
And so calling Fruit::getVal().